# cash award or money award?

Tags: vocabulary

I'm wondering whether "cash award" or "money award" is correct in the following. If both are ok, what's the difference? Suppose this is about a prize-giving event.

They gave me a cash / money award.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Anecdotally, I believe I see "cash award" almost universally.

Comment: I have a related question. Does "cash award" necessarily mean an award in cash, i..e. bills or coins? Can a cash award be a cheque?

Comment: Again anecdotally, "cash awards" can be (and usually are) checks (US spelling; UK/Commonwealth spelling 'cheque'); the usual implication is that the prize/award is money, as contrasted with merchandise.

Comment: I gotta agree with @JeffZeitlin on both counts there.

Comment: What are the prizes? Without context it is only about the definition of *cash* vs. *money*. I would say "cash" needs to be legal tender that can be spent as is, as opposed to cash equivalents.